# How to determine the length of a function?

Tags: c

Consider the following code that takes the function f(), copies the function itself in its entirety to a buffer, modifies its code and runs the altered function. In practice, the original function that returns number 22 is cloned and modified to return number 42.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ENOUGH 1000
#define MAGICNUMBER 22
#define OTHERMAGICNUMBER 42

int f(void)
{
    return MAGICNUMBER;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i,k;
    char buffer[ENOUGH];
    /* Pointer to original function f */
    int (*srcfptr)(void) = f;
    /* Pointer to hold the manipulated function */
    int (*dstfptr)(void) = (void*)buffer;
    char* byte;
    memcpy(dstfptr, srcfptr, ENOUGH);
    /* Replace magic number inside the function with another */
    for (i=0; i < ENOUGH; i++) {
        byte = ((char*)dstfptr)+i;
        if (*byte == MAGICNUMBER) {
            *byte = OTHERMAGICNUMBER;
        }
    }

    k = dstfptr();
    /* Prints the other magic number */
    printf("Hello %d!\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

The code now relies on just guessing that the function will fit in the 1000 byte buffer. It also violates rules by copying too much to the buffer, since the function f() will be most likely a lot shorter than 1000 bytes.

This brings us to the ***question***: Is there a method to figure out the size of any given function in C? Some methods include looking into intermediate linker output, and guessing based on the instructions in the function, but that's just not quite enough. Is there any way to be sure?

---

Please note: It compiles and works on my system but doesn't quite adhere to standards because conversions between function pointers and void* aren't exactly allowed:

```
$ gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic fptr.c -o fptr
fptr.c: In function 'main':
fptr.c:21: warning: ISO C forbids initialization between function pointer and 'void *'
fptr.c:23: warning: ISO C forbids passing argument 1 of 'memcpy' between function pointer and 'void *'
/usr/include/string.h:44: note: expected 'void * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'int (*)(void)'
fptr.c:23: warning: ISO C forbids passing argument 2 of 'memcpy' between function pointer and 'void *'
/usr/include/string.h:44: note: expected 'const void * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'int (*)(void)'
fptr.c:26: warning: ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to object pointer type
$ ./fptr
Hello 42!
$
```

Please note: on some systems executing from writable memory is not possible and this code will crash. It has been tested with gcc 4.4.4 on Linux running on x86_64 architecture.

Comment: No code that attempts anything like this can even remotely adhere to standards. There's no guarantee even that a function occupies contiguous space in memory. There's certainly no guarantee that the byte `MAGICNUMBER` won't appear in the function's code not representing the return value, but because it just so happens to be part of some opcode.

Comment: There is no requirement that the code for a function be contiguous. There is also no requirement that the compiler generate position-independent code. (Most don't.)

Comment: Or that the operating system will allow you to execute code that is on the stack.

Comment: Machines with [Harvard Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) won't let you easily convert function pointers to data pointers or the other way around and read/modify code directly in C.

Comment: Harvard Architecture is rather obsolete and is rather a curiosity for language lawyers. The other issues are all completely relevant, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in C. Even if you knew the length, the address of a function matters, because function calls and accesses to certain types of data will use **program-counter-relative** addressing. Thus, a copy of the function located at a different address will not do the same thing as the original. Of course there are many other issues too.

Comment: if hes on x64, he can emit PIC, which will solve one half of the problems

Comment: No, it won't solve the problems; PIC actually makes it worse. Non-PIC code will merely hard-code the absolute address of data it accesses, making it safe to run the **code** at a different address as long as it makes no function calls, but PIC code will code the relative address of the data (or of the GOT), which will be different if the function moves. PIC only works when the **entire DSO** is relocated together, with no internal relative addresses changing. It does not work on a single-function level.

Comment: this is the definition I'm using: "Position-independent code can be copied to any memory location and executed without modification" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code )

Comment: Well that definition does not match the actual real-world use of it (e.g. `-fPIC` in gcc) unless you interpret "code" as the entire DSO.

Comment: It depends on what you expect to happen to external references. One interpretation would be that the moved code would relocate with moved external references. (e.g., if you move a function that accesses a variable, then the moved function assumes the variable has also moved.) Another is that the moved code would relocate with shared external references. (A moved function accesses the original variable.) The definition you're using is ambiguous with respect to externals, and most people use the first interpretation (moved externals), since that interpretation is more useful.

Comment: Just as a note, I accepted this answer because it states the futility of manipulating any non-trivial (unlike the one I gave just as an example) functions.

Answer (score 1):

In the C standard, there is no notion of introspection or reflection, thus you'd need to devise a method yourself, as you have done, some other safer methods exists however.

There are two ways:

1. Disassemble the function (at *runtime*) till you hit the *final* `RETN`/`JMP`/etc, while accounting for switch/jump tables. This of course requires some heavy analysis of the function you disassemble (using an engine like [beaEngine](http://www.beaengine.org/)), this is of course the most reliable, but its slow and heavy.
2. Abuse compilation units, this is very risky, and not fool proof, but if you know you compiler generates functions sequentially in their compilation unit, you can do something along these lines:

   ```
   void MyFunc()
   {
       //...
   }

   void MyFuncSentinel()
   {
   }

   //somewhere in code
   size_t z = (uintptr_t)MyFuncSentinel - (uintptr_t)MyFunc;
   uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*)malloc(z);
   memcpy(buf,(char*)MyFunc,z);
   ```

   this will have some extra padding, but it will be minimal (and unreachable). although highly risky, its a lot faster that the disassemble method.

note: both methods will require that the target code has read permissions.

---

@R.. raises a very good point, your code won't be relocatable unless its PIC or you reassasmble it in-place to adjust the addresses etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standards compliant way of achieving the result you want:

```
int f(int magicNumber)
{
    return magicNumber;
}

int main(void)
{

    k = f(OTHERMAGICNUMBER);
    /* Prints the other magic number */
    printf("Hello %d!\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, you may have lots of uses of `f()` all over the place with no arguments and not want to go through your code changing every one, so you could do this instead

```
int f()
{
    return newf(MAGICNUMBER);
}

int newf(int magicNumber)
{
    return magicNumber;
}


int main(void)
{

    k = newf(OTHERMAGICNUMBER);
    /* Prints the other magic number */
    printf("Hello %d!\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not suggesting this is a direct answer to your problem but that what you are doing is so horrible, you need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can obtain the length of a function at runtime using labels:

```
int f()
{
    int length;
    start:
    length = &&end - &&start + 11; // 11 is the length of function prologue
                                   // and epilogue, got with gdb

    printf("Magic number: %d\n", MagicNumber);

    end:
    return length;
}
```

After executing this function we know its length, so we can `malloc` for the right length, copy and editing the code, then executing it.

```
int main()
{
    int (*pointerToF)(), (*newFunc)(), length, i;
    char *buffer, *byte;

    length = f();

    buffer = malloc(length);
    if(!buffer) {
        printf("can't malloc\n");
        return 0;
    }

    pointerToF = f;
    newFunc = (void*)buffer;
    memcpy(newFunc, pointerToF, length);

    for (i=0; i < length; i++) {
        byte = ((char*)newFunc)+i;
        if (*byte == MagicNumber) {
            *byte = CrackedNumber;
        }
    }

    newFunc();
}
```

Now there's another bigger problem though, the one @R. mentioned. Using this function once modified (correctly) results in segmentation fault when calling `printf` because the `call` instruction has to specify an *offset* which will be wrong. You can see this with `gdb`, using `disassemble f` to see the original code and `x/15i buffer` to see the edited one.
By the way, both my code and yours compile without warnings but crash on my machine (`gcc 4.4.3`) when calling the edited function.

Comment: Depending on compiler optimizations, you may discover that `end` comes *before* `start`.